# Can Visa delivery get delayed beyond travel dates?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, france

Is it possible given that the embassy keeps note of the travel itinerary that they complete processing and dispatch of my visa later than my departure dates?

Wouldn't they simply reject my application if they find me lacking in travel requirements etc?

I am asking this because my departure is in two days and I have still not got any update on my Visa. Tomorrow is the last day and I want to understand what are the chances of me getting it.

So basically what I am asking is whether it is possible (usual?) for an embassy to dispatch the Visa later than the travel plans.

Comment: When did you submit the application? Maybe the visa application simply didn't get processed yet?

Comment: What status was showing for your application when you checked online?

Comment: @Sabine I initially submitted the Visa a month back (28/3/22). They told me that a document was missing which I could submit by (18/4/22). My Visa is still under process since then.

Comment: @Traveller The status is: " Your VISA Application has been forwarded to the etc etc on 28/3/22" The status has been like that for very long.

Comment: In that case, your chances of getting the visa in time are vanishingly small IMHO

Comment: Note: You may get a longer visa, so that you can travel when you receive the passport (but often it is not possible/feasible to rebook travel easily). In any case, a non-used visa is far better then a rejected visa (the later has effect on many future visa applications). I suspect now a lot of people want to travel, so getting visa take longer then usual. And the "missing document" is often cause of troubles (high risk of getting thing "temporarily lost" in some stack of paper)

Answer (score 2):

> So basically what I am asking is whether it is possible (usual?) for an embassy to dispatch the Visa later than the travel plans.

It's possible, especially if the travel plans are inherently somewhat flexible (think visiting family vs. attending a conference). But you're right that the consulate could simply refuse the visa because you do not have a purpose anymore.

Comment: I am a student and have to be a part of an internship.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible given that the embassy keeps note of the travel itenary that they complete processing and dispatch of my Visa later than my departure dates?

Possible in theory but highly unlikely, they've most certainly just didn't have the time to process your visa yet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My flight is day after tomorrow. Tomorrow is the last day after which I will have to cancel or reschedule my plans. From the calls and mails I have done it seems nothing can be done to expedite or get any update from the embassy except just to wait. Do you think that's all I can do?